# SAS - Do looping from condition1 to condition2

Tags: macros, sas, do-loops, sas-studio

I am looking to have a programme which cleans up some messy data I have, I am looking to do this for both the assets and liabilities side of the project i'm working on.

My question is there a way to use a do loop to use the cleaning up data to first clean up the assets then liabilities. something like this:

```
%do %I = Asset %to Liability;

%assetorliability= I ;

proc sort data = &assetorliability;
by price;
run;

data want&assetorliability;
set &assetorliability;
if _N_ < 50000;
run;
```

the actual script is quite long so a singular macro may not be the ideal solution but this loop would be great.

TIA.

EDIT : the programme includes some macros and the errors received are as follows:

```
%let list =Asset Liability;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list,%str( )));

%let next=%scan(&list,&i,%str( ));

%Balance;

%end;
```

in the macro the data steps are named with a balance&list to allow for each scenario. the errors are:

```
13221  %let list =Asset Liability;
13222  %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list,%str( )));
ERROR: The %DO statement is not valid in open code.
13223
13224  %let next=%scan(&list,&i,%str( ));
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I not resolved.
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric
       operand is required. The condition was: &i
ERROR: Argument 2 to macro function %SCAN is not a number.
ERROR: The %END statement is not valid in open code.
```

Comment: If you want to use `%do` (or `%if`) then you need wrap it into a macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `%do` statement is not as flexible as the data step `do` statement. To loop over a list of values you would want to put the list into a macro variable and use an index variable in your `%do` loop.

Note that macro logic needs to be inside of a macro. You cannot use it in "open" code.

```
%macro do_over(list);
%local i next;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list,%str( )));
  %let next=%scan(&list,&i,%str( ));
  proc sort data = &next ;
    by price;
  run;

  data want&next ;
  ...
%end;
%mend do_over ;
%do_over(Asset Liability)
```

Comment: So, I tried to run the code and I received some errors. I am extending my query to ask about running a loop on asset and liabilities but on a series of macros so it would look something like this

Comment: Not sure what your comment about series of macros mean, but the error in your updated question is clear. You tried to use `%do` outside of a macro definition. Wrap the code inside of a macro definition and then call the macro.